# SQL: M:N relationship between objects with version range

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design, many-to-many

I need to rework current representation M:N relationships from row per new version for object because generates many duplicated rows:

**Object table**

```
create table tmp_objects(id_obj number, version number, other_data varchar2(100));
-- Object 1
insert into tmp_objects(id_obj, version, other_data) values (1,1,'something');
insert into tmp_objects(id_obj, version, other_data) values (1,2,'something else');
insert into tmp_objects(id_obj, version, other_data) values (1,3,'nothing');
commit;
-- Object 2
insert into tmp_objects(id_obj, version, other_data) values (2,1,'2 something');
insert into tmp_objects(id_obj, version, other_data) values (2,2,'2 something else');
insert into tmp_objects(id_obj, version, other_data) values (2,3,'2 nothing');
commit;
```

**Curent relationships (row per new object version)**

```
create table tmp_old_rels(id_rel number, id_obj_1 number, version_1 number,id_obj_2 number, version_2 number, rel_data varchar2(100)); 
-- Data
insert into tmp_old_rels(id_rel, id_obj_1, version_1, id_obj_2, version_2, rel_data) values (1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 'same');
insert into tmp_old_rels(id_rel, id_obj_1, version_1, id_obj_2, version_2, rel_data) values (2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 'same');
insert into tmp_old_rels(id_rel, id_obj_1, version_1, id_obj_2, version_2, rel_data) values (3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 'same');
insert into tmp_old_rels(id_rel, id_obj_1, version_1, id_obj_2, version_2, rel_data) values (4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 'same');
insert into tmp_old_rels(id_rel, id_obj_1, version_1, id_obj_2, version_2, rel_data) values (5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 'different');
insert into tmp_old_rels(id_rel, id_obj_1, version_1, id_obj_2, version_2, rel_data) values (6, 1, 2, 2, 2, 'different');
insert into tmp_old_rels(id_rel, id_obj_1, version_1, id_obj_2, version_2, rel_data) values (7, 1, 2, 2, 3, 'different');
insert into tmp_old_rels(id_rel, id_obj_1, version_1, id_obj_2, version_2, rel_data) values (8, 1, 3, 2, 1, 'different');
insert into tmp_old_rels(id_rel, id_obj_1, version_1, id_obj_2, version_2, rel_data) values (9, 1, 3, 2, 2, 'different');
insert into tmp_old_rels(id_rel, id_obj_1, version_1, id_obj_2, version_2, rel_data) values (10, 1, 3, 2, 3, 'different');
commit;
```

**New planned relationships (row per unique id_obj_1, id_obj_2, rel_data with version ranges)**

```
create table tmp_new_rels (id_rel number, id_obj_1 number, version_1_from number,version_1_to number,id_obj_2 number, version_2_from number,version_2_to number, rel_data varchar2(100));
-- Data
insert into tmp_new_rels(id_rel, id_obj_1, version_1_from, version_1_to, id_obj_2, version_2_from, version_2_to, rel_data) values (1,1, 1, 2, 2 , 1, 2, 'same');
insert into tmp_new_rels(id_rel, id_obj_1, version_1_from, version_1_to, id_obj_2, version_2_from, version_2_to, rel_data) values (2,1, 2, 3, 2 , 1, 3, 'different'); 
commit;
```

Is there a better way for representing M:N relationship, where every object have snapshots in time and relationships between them has to be as range ?

Comment: I've tried to discern how the objects are connected but can't get the connection. What, for example, does it mean for 'something' to be the same as '2 something else'? And why isn't object (1,3) the same as object (2,3)? You also mention "snapshot in time" but there are no time values anywhere.

Comment: Values of column "other_data" has no meaning for the problem. The reason why i choose to add the column is that there is a "other data" which is relevant for not to group together multiple version of object. For example time of record creation is one of them.
Also this time is irrelevant for solution of the problem. The Version column is defacto this "mark" of creation. Every time when new record of same object is created, this new record gets an incremental number for version.

Answer (score 0):

You may benefit from versioning your data. [Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114580/best-way-to-design-a-database-and-table-to-keep-records-of-changes/114738#114738) is an answer I gave that refers to a lot of additional information, including the queries to access the data including joins between versioned (historical) and non-versioned data.